# ASP.NET 2.0 has not been registered on the web server IIS10 Windows 10

Tags: iis, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a web app in Visual Studio 2010 and receive the following warning message when attempting to open the solution:

"ASP.NET 2.0 has not been registered on the Web Server. You need to manually configure you Web server for ASP.NET 2.0 in order for your site to run correctly."

My setup is asp.net 2.0, IIS10 and Windows 10 Premium.

What could I do to remove this warning?

Comment: Why are you targeting ASP.NET 2.0, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ensure you have the .NET Framework 3.5 installed via Control Panel > Programs and Features
2. Ensure your IIS Application Pool is configured to use the .NET 2.0 CLR (IIS Manager > Application Pools > (Your pool) > Basic Settings
3. Run `aspnet_regiis.exe` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx for a complete reference) to ensure it is registered with IIS, make sure you're running the 2.0 CLR version instead of the 4.0 CLR version.

Comment: Thank you Dai, your step 2 along with setting Visual Studio to open in Administrator Mode has resolved the problem